Is this a vote registration bug which should be taken to meta.stackexchange.com?
When searching for questions with open questions with no answers using answers:0 closed:no I got the following in the search results.

When going into the question there was an upvote.
Going back and refreshing did not change the number of votes registered.
Not that this should matter necessarily if you can answer the question, but surely when a vote is cast it should be registered in the search results if the info is given.
Is there a reason known for this or should this be taken to the StackExchange staff for review?
Incidentally, I typed this out, opened another tab to see if it is the same before posting and a 1 is showing now when it wasn't a moment ago.

This is most likely by design in order to be able to scale the site.
Sometimes you need to rely on "eventual consistency" between different servers doing different things with the data (in order to scale the site to handle more simultaneous requests). Here: indexing the questions with vote counts vs. presenting the question.
Just consider that the server which gives you the search results is a different server than the one that displays the question and votes. Eventual consistency means that the two can go "out of sync" (because of the inherent nature of network connections). They are only "eventually consistent". Once the up vote arrives at the indexing server, then it will correspond to what you see on the question.
This improves scalability of the site since you now have two separate servers that provide functionality to end users; they don't block one another. This is what is called horizontal scalability, as opposed to vertical scalability which would involve adding more CPUs to a single server/increasing working memory, etc.

Thanks for that. Although I am not a computer science person I understood this answer which helps.

https://shouldiblamecaching.com/
